# Way to select between real autoconfigured bean and a stub bean in test application context

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I would like to run most of my Spring Boot tests using a stub bean (which basically does nothing), but some tests should actually use the real Spring Boot's autoconfigured bean. How can I have the stub bean in the test context by default, but conditionally switch it out with the real bean?

All my tests are derived from a few superclasses which provide the correct test setup, and this specific bean setup is orthogonal to that, so I *cannot*:

- Create two new/different superclasses, one for the stub and one for the real one
- Use `@MockBean` in the test class, because most times I want to have the stub, and not need to remember to add this
- Use `@MockBean` in the superclasses, because I wouldn't know how to override the mock in my specific test classes where I want the Spring Boot autoconfigured mock.

I'm looking for a simple-to-use solution like a JUnit-Rule; an annotation on the test class together with a TestExecutionListener; or something else similar.

Note that the real bean is a fully autoconfigured bean, I don't have any configuration for it in my production code (just in the `application.properties`) - it is actually the `JavaMailSender` but that detail shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use different profiles for that. You can annotate your test classes with `@ActiveProfiles("myprofile")` or whatever profile you want to use for that test. Then add two different bean configurations and specify the profiles there as well (`@Profile("myprofile")`).

Comment: Thanks. I already have a test profile which I always want to be active. Now as mentioned in my question, in one of my scenarios I don't want to have any custom beans defined (to trigger Spring Boot's autoconfigured bean config). So after a bit of thought, while your solution is workable, it would be a bit messy in my opinion, I would need to have configurations with negated profiles or with more complicated boolean logic in the profiles - also doesn't seem very maintainable to me.

Comment: Oh. ok. In your question you just talk about "a bean". If it is lots of beans then this would really get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Not very discoverable, and it goes deep into the Spring TestContext Framework, but this is a solution that solves the requirement in the question:

Register a `ContextCustomizerFactory` in `META-INF/spring.factories`, which, depending on some marker on the current test class, either registers a `ContextCustomizer` or doesn't.
The `ContextCustomizer` in turn registers a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which removes the original production bean from the BeanRegistry and adds the mock bean instead.

So it works slightly the other way around as in the question. Rather than having the mock bean in the context by default, it loads the production config as default, and at the end swaps the undesired production bean out if needed.

Add  `META-INF/spring.factories` in the test resources:

```
org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory=my.package.MyContextCustomizerFactory
```

Add these classes to your test sources:

```java
public class MyContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

  @Override
  public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(
      Class<?> testClass, List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
    
    // Your logic to decide based on the testClass whether you want the real bean or the mock.
    // See other ContextCustomizerFactories provided by Spring for how you can look at fields and annotations on the test class etc.
    boolean shouldSwapBeanWithMock = ...

    if (shouldSwapBeanWithMock) {
      return new MyContextCustomizer();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static class MyContextCustomizer implements ContextCustomizer {

    /**
     * ContextCustomizers are called very early in the application context lifecycle, where not all
     * beans are registered yet. This is why we must register first a {@link
     * BeanFactoryPostProcessor} which will do the bean swap, instead of doing it in the Customizer
     * directly.
     */
    @Override
    public void customizeContext(
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
      context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor());
    }

    /**
     * ContextCustomizers are part of the key which decides if an ApplicationContext can be
     * retrieved from cache or needs to be freshly instantiated. {@code equals} and {@code hashCode}
     * are overridden for that reason, because multiple instances of this Customizer are equivalent.
     * The cache key should only depend on whether this customizer was present in the context or
     * not.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return (obj != null) && (obj.getClass() == getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return getClass().hashCode();
    }

  }

  private static class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
      // select whichever bean type you want to swap here
      String[] beansToSwap = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(JavaMailSender.class, false, false);

      Arrays.stream(beansToSwap)
          .forEach(((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory)::removeBeanDefinition);

      // register your mock bean as singleton or however you like
      beanFactory.registerSingleton(MyMockMailSender.class.getName(), new MyMockMailSender());
    }
  }
}
```